# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when trying to install extensions in VS Code W11

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, windows-11

I am getting this error in VS Code trying to install an extension:

```
[error] net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET: Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:105:7047)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (node:events:526:28)
```

When VS Code is opened I also get this errors:

```
2023-03-16 19:51:48.832 [info] Electron sandbox mode is enabled!
2023-03-16 19:51:49.171 [error] Extension 'tabnine.tabnine-vscode' wants API proposal 'inlineCompletions' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-03-16 19:51:51.706 [error] RequestService#request (browser) - error https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery {}
2023-03-16 19:51:51.831 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 37ms
```

I know that one of the errors is related to another extension I have installed but looks related to a kind of network error. Yesterday everything was working perfectly, I updated Windows 11 (as it forced me to do it) and today when I tried to come back to my projects I get this.

Also rebooted the router and got this when trying to download the extension again:

```
2023-03-16 20:08:00.671 [error] Canceled: Canceled: Canceled
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:21:11379
    at S.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:19:145)
    at m.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:19:2066)
    at h.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:19:1704)
    at R.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:19:5669)
    at D.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:19:6083)
    at Object.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:21:11530)
    at X.cancel (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:90782)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:80015
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at W.z (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:79993)
    at async W.installFromGallery (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:75037)
```

I have been looking for solutions and all are like firewall/antivirus deactivation, what I tried and I get:

`2023-03-16 19:57:00.011 [error] Error: XHR failed at v.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/malve/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:72:1399)`

and not any other log. Also tried flushing dns but nothing.

Any other network related software is working perfectly.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/codota/tabnine-vscode/issues/974, https://github.com/codota/tabnine-vscode/issues/895. Note: If you end up raising your own GitHub issue ticket, please link to it in your question post for posterity.

Comment: What version of VS Code do you have installed, and what version of TabNine extension do you have?